# Assignment Operator in constructors

Tags: c++, constructor

Why is it that i cant do this onto my constructor

```
Person::Person(std:: string tname,int tage):
    name=tname,
    age=tage
{}
```

But its perfectly fine to do this

```
Person::Person(std:: string tname,int tage):
    name(tname),
    age(tage)
{}
```

Where name is a string member variable and age is an int member variable.

??

Comment: Because the latter is the syntax chosen by the designer of the C++ language, while the former isn't.

Comment: Does it mean that i cant use 'this' keyword outside my constructor

Comment: @SaurabhKumar You can't use `this` outside of non-static member functions (including constructors).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that because that isn't the syntax of the C++ language.

The reason it is written that way is that (at least for class members) the initialiser calls the constructor of the class with the provided parameters. It doesn't create the types and then assign values to them. The whole point of using initialisers rather than assigning to values in the body of the constructor is avoiding the double step of constructing an object then assigning a value to it.

If you have 3 classes `A`, `B` and `C` where `C` has members `a` of type `A` and `b` of type `B` then this constructor:

```
C() :
  a(1234),
  a(4567)
{
}
```

would be equivalent to the following code outside of a class:

```
A a(1234);
B b(4567);
```

Whereas this constructor:

```
C()
{
   a = 1234;
   b = 4567;
}
```

Is equivalent to:

```
A a; // default construct a
B b; // default construct b
a = 1234;
b = 4567;
```

In these simple cases the compiler will probably optimise out these small differences but for more complicated member objects the default construction followed by assignment could be expensive or even impossible (e.g. if the member object has no default constructor).

Comment: Wait, you can have a data member declared like this `int foo = 42;` and that is OK. So your argument doesn't hold. Also `=` doesn't mean assignment when used in initialization.

Comment: @juanchopanza integers don't have constructors... Also note that `A a = 1234` and `A a; a = 1234` are different things. The first on a modern compiler will actually call the `A(int)` constructor

Comment: Oh come on. That is irrelevant but OK then, `std::string foo = "hello";`

Comment: The point is that the syntax shown by OP could have been valid and compatible with other C++ initialization syntax rules. This is initialization: `int foo = 42`. This could also have been initialization: `Foo(int n) : n_ = n {}`

Comment: @juanchopanza only on recent versions of c++, older versions didn't have this optimisation (at least in the standard as far as I know) so officially at least `std::string foo = "hello";` would construct a string then assign "hello" to it.

Comment: Sorry, no, that is incorrect. It is initialization according to the language grammar, that's all there is to it. There is no assignment going on there.

Comment: @juanchopanza only since c++11 and even then its optional see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision

Comment: No, since before C++98. That part of the grammar hasn't changed. It has nothing to do with copy elision.